# Choosing arguments in tidy

Tags: r, spatial, tidy, broom

In a SpatialDataFrame I have the following structure for the data.

```
> str(shapedata_trans@data)
'data.frame':   4066 obs. of  6 variables:
 $ OBJECTID  : num  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 $ PC4       : Factor w/ 4066 levels "1011","1012",..: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 $ Aantal_mul: Factor w/ 11 levels "1","10","12",..: 1 1 5 7 1 1 5 1 1 1 ...
 $ Aantal_adr: Factor w/ 2653 levels "1","10","100",..: 2404 2599 320 383 97 2604 60 211 63 1450 ...
 $ Shape_Leng: num  5908 5489 19421 15356 4733 ...
 $ Shape_Area: num  1034025 1214502 5075544 2674418 770406 ...
```

And in addition to that it has more information about the polygons and their coordinates... Which is great.
However, in order to reduce this to a simple table we can use ggplo2::fortify or broom::tidy

```
> fort_PC = fortify(shapedata_trans)
> head(fort_PC)
      long      lat order  hole piece group id
1 4.906544 52.37910     1 FALSE     1   0.1  0
2 4.906733 52.37906     2 FALSE     1   0.1  0
3 4.906739 52.37908     3 FALSE     1   0.1  0
4 4.907138 52.37901     4 FALSE     1   0.1  0
5 4.908692 52.37881     5 FALSE     1   0.1  0
6 4.909105 52.37875     6 FALSE     1   0.1  0
```

However I want to add the information in the @data part to this final table.. Information like the columns PC4, Aantal_mul, Aantal_adr, Shape_Area and Shape_Leng. I know that in fortify/tidy I can specify the region by saying

```
> head(fortify(shapedata_trans,region = c("PC4")))
      long      lat order  hole piece   id  group
1 4.906544 52.37910     1 FALSE     1 1011 1011.1
2 4.906733 52.37906     2 FALSE     1 1011 1011.1
3 4.906739 52.37908     3 FALSE     1 1011 1011.1
4 4.907138 52.37901     4 FALSE     1 1011 1011.1
5 4.908692 52.37881     5 FALSE     1 1011 1011.1
6 4.909105 52.37875     6 FALSE     1 1011 1011.1
```

But this doesnt make it better. Does anyone have a solution?

Comment: `merge(fortify(shapedata_trans), shapedata_trans@data, by.x="id", by.y="OBJECTID", all=TRUE)` ?

Comment: Wow.. cant think why I didnt think of this before..

Comment: How can I make your comment 'the answer' and put this thing to solved ?(Im quite new to stack..)

Comment: if i am not wrong, you need to wait some time before you can answer your own question. just use it in your work and move on.

Comment: Thanks, I think the problem I had before was using this merged caused the polygons to get all messed up somehow. But probably did something wrong somewhere

Comment: Check for dupes OBJECTID

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Chinsoon12

merge(fortify(shapedata_trans), shapedata_trans@data, by.x="id", by.y="OBJECTID", all=TRUE)

Thanks again!